# MinGW C++ Eclipse CDT program terminates instantly

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have been trying for hours to get a test SDL program up and running, but no matter what I try, it instantly terminates upon launching.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>
#undef main
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    const int WIDTH = 800, HEIGHT = 600, SDLWP = SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED;
        if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
            cout << "SDL not working." << endl;
        }
        cout << "SDL working properly." << endl;

        SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("Test", SDLWP, SDLWP, WIDTH, HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

        if(window == NULL) {
            SDL_Quit();
        }

        bool quit = false;

        SDL_Event event;

        while(!quit) {
            while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
                if(event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                    quit = true;
                }
            }
        }

        SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
        SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

I have gotten the program to actually do something by having this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        cout << "SDL working properly." << endl;
}
```

Also, about the #undef main part, I need that because otherwise, the program will think that I am calling SDL_main.

Here is the library search path if that helps: 
C:\Users\ (my username)\Desktop\SDL2-2.0.4\i686-w64-mingw32\lib

And the libraries themselves, written in order from top to bottom:

mingw32 
SDL2main 
SDL2

No other library path will give me no compiler errors except: 
C:\Users\ (my username)\Desktop\SDL2-2.0.4\lib\x86

So it seems that the root of problem is:

```
#include <SDL.h>
```

Comment: What happens when you debug the program?  If you single step (step over) how far do you get?

Comment: @RichardCritten I get this: [New Thread 6448.0x22fc] [New Thread 6448.0xef4] [New Thread 6448.0x14ac] [New Thread 6448.0xa54]

Comment: @RichardCritten the numbers and codes change every time, and it still terminates instantly, even though I put breakpoints in places

Comment: Did you solve your problem? If so, it might be useful for others if you said how. If not - did you try running gdb from a terminal?

Comment: @HighCommander4 For some reason I solved the issue by using Visual Studio. Not sure why Eclipse did not like SDL